# Gracefully terminate keep-alive connections in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, keep-alive, cloudflare

Cloudflare now reuses several keep-alive connections to proxy incoming connections which is good for resource usage, but makes it quite a pain to cleanly disconnect a worker from them. Before they did this you could simply remove a worker from the load balancer set and no new requests would go to that worker, while existing requests would continue to be processed. Now that they use keep-alives they don't need to initiate new connections and so removing a worker from the load balancer queue no longer stops new requests coming in over those existing keep-alive connections.

I could simply call `connection.destroy()` on each connection after a given timeout, but that would potentially disrupt valid requests. I could also call that after each `res.end` call, but since requests share connections one request may kill the connection another request is using. The same applies with setting a low timeout such as `connection.setTimeout(1000)`.

Is there a good way to reject additional requests from a keep-alive socket while allowing it to finish all current requests? It would be nice to be able to simply notify cloudflare in some way that a socket should no longer be used for incoming requests, but I'm not sure that is possible.

I feel like some sort of half-open socket would do the trick, but executing on that seems a bit tricky.